# Deploy Single Page Application to Azure Cloud Service

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure

I am currently creating a dashboard for a complex backend that should be hosted on an Azure Cloud Service due to performance reasons. Unlike our older projects we want to implement our dashboard as single page application based on vue.js, but after doing some initial research I am aware of difficulties when it comes to deployment.

The idea is to have a frontend project and an ASP.NET Web Api that offers the respective data for the dashboard. Both projects should run inside the cloud service.

What would be the best approach to deploy single page applications to a cloud service? Since we prefer Visual Studio Code over Visual Studio for frontend-related tasks, it would be great if we won't depend on specific features VS offers.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is too broad and opinion-based, and is off-topic for Stack Overflow. That said: Cloud Services (web & worker roles) have very limited deployment options, and are only directly supported via Visual Studio and Eclipse (as well as CLI). You'll need to work out your deployment scheme via startup script support, if it's beyond anything you want to bundle directly into the package.

Comment: What issues are you facing with a standard FTP deployment to a App Service?